# what does "aq" mean when joining two data object together?

Tags: javascript, data-analysis

Tried to join two data together in javascript but cant figure out what does "aq" mean here.

```
data = aq
  .from(demand)
  .join(aq.from(temperature_with_features))
  .rename({ air_temp: "temp", value: "demand" })
  .select(aq.not("id", "name"))
  .objects()
```

The complete code is here:https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/correlation-over-time

Comment: That is `Arquero` library and you can [read here](https://observablehq.com/@uwdata/introducing-arquero) and at [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/arquero)

Comment: thx very much for the info